# Quicksilver Lite under Windows: anonymous E-mail successfully sent but nothing received in the Mailbox

Tags: anonymous, quicksilver

Quicksilver Lite under Windows: anonymous E-mail  successfully sent but nothing received in the Mailbox !

Does somebody know what is the problem here ?
Example follows:

```
Fcc: outbox
Host: smtp.gmail.com
From: sender@gmail.com
Chain: *,*,*; copies=2;
To: destinator@yahoo.fr
Subject: Hello Dear How are you?

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla

See u next

~~
```

Comment: The 3 remailer-Server have to temporally pool them before sending, thats why there is a time lag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Email goes around 3 Remailer-Server, but are not instantly relayed to the next Remailer.They have to be temporally pooled before got sending, thats why there is a time lag...